# MATLAB: Two different type of column bind

Tags: matlab

I am trying to have a matrix like the following

```
12 A
15 A
10 A
 4 B
23 C
66 C
45 C
77 C
```

so i have tried :

```
 data = [12;15;10;4;23;66;45;77];
 abc = ['A';'A';'A';'B';'C';'C';'C';'C'];

data_abc = [data abc]

data_abc =
```

I am not understanding the result it showing.

How can i get my desired format ? That is, one column will contain numerical data and another  column will contain characters as i first showed the structure.

Comment: Please can you format your post better? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you are trying to display numbers with strings in the same class array. you could have used `num2str(data)` but if I were you I'd save into a cell format:

```
abc = {'A';'A';'A';'B';'C';'C';'C';'C'};
data = {12;15;10;4;23;66;45;77};

[data abc]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've already got your data in array format, use `num2cell` and `cellstr` to convert to `cell` format, then you can concatenate like you're trying to do:

```
[num2cell(data) cellstr(abc)]

ans = 

    [12]    'A'
    [15]    'A'
    [10]    'A'
    [ 4]    'B'
    [23]    'C'
    [66]    'C'
    [45]    'C'
    [77]    'C'
```

Comment: As @natan points out, you can of course also save your data in cell format from the get-go if you have access to that part of the code.